# Self referential C99 initializers

Tags: c

Consider:

```
struct N {
  struct N *next, *prev;
};

struct X {
  struct N *first, *last;
};

int fun()
{
  struct X tmp = {
    .first = &(struct N) {.next = ???},
    .last  = &(struct N) {.prev = ???},
  };

  return 0;
}

void main()
{
  fun();
}
```

I come across situations, like the above, where it would be really useful to be able to get a pointer to the structure I'm initializing as part of the initialization process.  Something like "this" in C++.  I realize I can use the name of the variable, but that precludes doing something like:

```
struct X x = MAGIC_INITIALIZER_MACRO;
```

Is there a way to do this?

And as long as I'm on the subject of initialization, if the order of the initialization statements doesn't match the order they are declared in the structure, which order does the compiler use?

Comment: There is no way to use the initializers for pointers. You have to explicitly `malloc` (for pointers whose lifetime outlives the enclosing function), or initialize a regular auto struct and take the address of that (lifetime ends when the function ends). The best you can do is abstract the malloc part out into a function, something like `struct N* create_N(struct N* next)`

Comment: Regarding order of initialization - it doesn't matter what order you use in the designated initializer - the order in which each member is initialized is not defined by the standard and hence you have no guarantees on it.

Comment: You can of course make a macro of the form `DECLARE_AND_INITIALIZE(x);`.

Comment: It may be possible, but it depends on a number of things. Where do you want the `N` nodes to be allocated: static, heap or stack? How many nodes do you expect to define in the initializer, one or an arbitrary number? If more than one, will the nodes always be in a straightforward back-and-forth sequential order? Please specify your use case, to prevent an XY-problem.

Comment: Where do you want the pointers to point to?

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```c
struct X createX(struct N *n) {
    n->next = n->prev = n;
    return (struct X) { .first = n, .last = n };
}

#define MAGIC_INITIALIZER_MACRO createX(&(struct N){0})

int main() {
  struct X x = MAGIC_INITIALIZER_MACRO;

  #define DBG(V) printf(#V " = %p\n", (void*)(V));
  DBG(x.first);
  DBG(x.last);
  DBG(x.first->next);
  DBG(x.first->prev);

  return 0;
}
```

On my machine it produced the expected output:

```
x.first = 0x7fff22f32ab0
x.last = 0x7fff22f32ab0
x.first->next = 0x7fff22f32ab0
x.first->prev = 0x7fff22f32ab0
```

Lifetime of the compound literal inside the macro is the same as `x`.